# Forwarding reference for return type

Tags: c++, c++14, forwarding-reference

Is there a difference between those those two

```cpp
struct S;
int& foo(S&);

auto&& bar1(S& s) {
    return foo(s);
}

decltype(auto) bar2(S& s) {
    return foo(s);
}
```

for the compiler? I've been always using `decltype(auto)` in cases like this but is seems `auto&&` does the trick. Is it a coincidence or are both the identical?

Comment: the return type of `bar` is deduced from the return type of `foo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your particular case it results in the same: The deduced return type of both `bar1()` and `bar2()` is `int&`.

However, note that `auto&&` always results in a reference, i.e., `bar1()` is always going to return *by reference* regardless of whether `foo()` returns by value or by reference. On the other hand, declaring `bar2()` return's type as `decltype(auto)` will result in `bar2()` returning *by value* if `foo(s)` returns by value (which is not your case).

I guess you want to perfectly forward the object returned by `foo(s)`. If so, that is actually `decltype(auto)`'s use case. Think of it: if `foo()` had returned by value, then `bar1()`'s return type would have been deduced to `int&`, i.e., returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: OK, now I get it. By some reason I thought the same mechanism may kick in as with forwarding/universal reference. But it's not in template context, obviously.. Silly question. Thanks!

Comment: Return type `auto&&` does use the same mechanism as with forwarding reference function parameters. Both are always references - but a reference return type is more dangerous than a reference function parameter type.